# Problems with umlauts (can't type in terminal + can't open files)

Tags: character-encoding, special-characters

On my laptop I have Linux Mint 18.3 installed and right now I am experiencing the following problem:
As a German I happen to have some files (or directories) that contain umlauts in their names (which in itself is not the problem). If I now try to open those files (e.g. PDFs) that either contain an umlaut or are located in a (sub-)directory whose name contains an umlaut it won't open.

For example I have a directory named `Übungsblätter` and somewhere in that dir I have a few PDF files. If I try to open one of those files from the file manager Okular will tell me it can't open `.../ÃbungsblÃ¤tter/...` which shows me that it messed up the path by replacing the umlauts with some weird characters.

However if I have Okular opened and use its menu to open the respective file everything works like charm so the problem does only occur when trying to open the files from my file manager (Dolphin).

Furthermore I experienced that I can't type in umlauts in my terminal. I found [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/403753/cannot-type-any-special-character-or-umlaut-in-terminal) dealing with that specific problem and I hoped that would fix the file-issue as well. However that was not the case although I am now able to type in umlauts in the terminal (though when typing in an umlaut it will insert two characters. For example when typing in `ö` it will insert the two characters `\udcc3\udcb6` (found out by typing in `ö` and hitting return afterwards). It does get displayed as a single `ö` though but I have to explicitly delete two characters in order for the command line to be empty again.

Here's the output of `locale`:

```
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TIME=nds_DE.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_NAME=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

EDIT:
I just found out that when opening the respective PDF from the terminal it will also error in a similar way as when opening from the file manager but this time it says it can't open `.../bungsbltter/...` (It completely removes the umlauts)

EDIT2:
Output of `locale -a`:

```
C
C.UTF-8
de_DE.utf8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
POSIX
```

EDIT 3:
`/etc/default/locale`:

```
LANGUAGE=en_GB.utf8
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: Your locale output shows an error. Maybe it helps to set it up: [Arch wiki: locale](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/locale). Debian provides a package `locales-all` to make things easier, may help you, too.

Comment: can you try running: sudo locale-gen "de_DE.UTF-8" - followed by: sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales - and see if locale still complains afterwards?

Comment: Still complains... And `locale -a` still doesn't display the `de_DE.UTF-8`

Comment: @mviereck I tried but I don't even have an idea where to start... Even the linked wiki page didn't help me because I have no idea where a directory-error could come up in that context.

Comment: can you try exporting them temporarily before reconfiguring, then logging out and back in (for a reload) and see if that sticks? "export LANG=de_DE.UTF-8; export LANGUAGE=de_DE.UTF-8; export LC_ALL=de_DE.UTF-8; locale-gen de_DE.UTF-8; dpkg-reconfigure locales"

Comment: Problem still persists. Though if I now run `locale` it gives different errors: `locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
`

Comment: Can you show `cat /etc/default/locale` and, if it exists, `cat  /etc/locale.conf`?

Comment: I updated my question with the respective information. `/etc/locale.conf` does not exist on my system

Comment: What happens if you change to an existing locale, such as `de_DE.utf8`? I suppose `LANG` in `/etc/default/locale` should also be changed to an existing locale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see some confusion in the locale settings.

One point is: A mix of `de_DE`, `en_US` and `en_GB`.

The other point is: some locales are declared with `.utf8`, other with `.UTF-8`. Though it should mean the same, it may cause trouble.

The error message `Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory` is probably because of missing `en_US.UTF-8` in `locale -a` (that  has `en_US.utf8` instead), but it is declared in `/etc/default/locale`.

I am a bit confused to see `LANG=de_DE.UTF-8` in the output of `locale` although it is not defined in `/etc/default/locale` and there is no `/etc/locale.conf`. Maybe a setting from the desktop environment that overwrites system settings? Or in `~/.bashrc`? Also check whether you have a `~/.config/locale.conf`. More possible locations where environment variables can be set are listed in [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Environment_variables#Defining_variables). Find out where `LANG=de_DE.UTF-8` is set and remove that.

---

I think the best way is to set everything to german locales. Your `locale -a` shows installed locales on your system. One of them is `de_DE.utf8`.

The core setting is in `/etc/default/locale`. You can edit that manually and I think its content should be just `LANG=de_DE.utf8` and nothing else. You can edit the file yourself, or use a tool for this:

```
update-locale --reset LANG=de_DE.utf8
```

To keep the system in english, but have umlauts too, it may work to set the locale to `en_US.utf8` that is listed in `locale -a`. utf8 should provide the umlauts, even though the language does not use them:

```
update-locale --reset LANG=en_US.utf8
```

Speak a prayer, reboot and check if all is right. If console works fine, but there is still something wrong in desktop environment, check your desktop settings GUI for language entries and set is to `de_DE.utf8`, too.

Comment: Thanks I'll try tomorrow! However: Wouldn't that then set my system's language to German? I'd like to keep my system English...

Comment: @Raven I've added a setting to keep the system in english.

Comment: So I changed `/etc/default/locale` to `LANG=en_US.utf8` and I removed a line from my `~/.profile` file that set the `de_DE.UTF-8` thing. However that didn't affect the output of `locale` after a reboot and when using `update-locale --reset LANG=en_US.utf8` it tells me `perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = "en_US",
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LANG = "nds_DE.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").`

Comment: Okay nvm: I got it working. I had to follow the instructions listed [here](https://www.linuxbabe.com/linux-server/how-to-solve-perl-warning-setting-locale-failed) and do a reboot after that. Then I was able to use `update-locale --reset LANG=en_US.utf8` without it resulting in an error. However if I now use `locale` in the terminal it will tell me everything is set to `nds_DE.UTF-8` (which I generated in the previously mentioned step) (except the `LANGUAGE` that is set to `en_US`. That seems a bit odd to me but as I said: It seems to be working now so I won't complain.