# Can't type ^ and `

Tags: keyboard

I recently had problems with not being able to type in umlauts into the terminal which was resolved [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/425929/problems-with-umlauts-cant-type-in-terminal-cant-open-files).

Umlauts are working fine, but now I can't type in a `^` and a ` (Can't put it in code-tags as it is the code-encloser on this site). The strange thing is that this does only apply to some application of which the terminal is one (alongside with TeXStudio, KWrite and Kate).

In my Firefox browser and in LibreOffice (only tested in Calc so far) the keyboard works just as expected.

I did check for the keyboard layout but that is set correctly. The rest of the keyboard is also working as expected (I can even use `°` which is on the same key as `^`).

Therefore my question is if someone has any idea where this problem might come from and how I might be able to fix it.

I'm running Linux Mint 18.3 alongside the 4.10.0-38-generic kernel.
In case it is important: Here's the output of `locale`:

```
LANG=nds_DE.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="nds_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="nds_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="nds_DE.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="nds_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="nds_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="nds_DE.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="nds_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="nds_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="nds_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="nds_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="nds_DE.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="nds_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: What happens when you type `^` and an `a`? Or a `^` and a space?

Comment: If I do it in Firefox I get a `â` or a `^` respectively but if I do it in the terminal I simple get a normal `a` or a normal space. I did also find out that pressing `^` followed by anything else in the login-screen in the password field the whole thing freezes completely. So it is doing _something_ after all.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around this problem by using another keyboard layout variation: `German (Macintosh, elimitate dead key)`.

This eliminates the dead keys completely though, so that I can't type any accented letters using dead keys.